# Replace specific parts of string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, space

I've got a string and I'm trying to replace all &nbsp within tags with empty spaces.
All &nbsp outside of the tag should however not be replaced, what i would basically need to do is check whether the &nbsp string has "< a" (without the space) in front of it. For example if I had the string:

```
&nbsp<a&nbsphref="#"></a>
```

Then this should be turned into:

```
&nbsp<a href="#"></a>
```

Is there a way to check whether the &nbsp string has "< a" before it and if it does replace it?
I've had a look at the javascript replace function and i know how to replace all &nbsp strings, but not only ones with a specific string infront..
Hope that makes sense and let me know if you have any ideas, thanks :)

Comment: And why are you not fixing the code that is generating this mess?

Comment: The problem is that I'm displaying the content of a textbox in a div, so i have to change spaces in the string to &nbsp otherwise the browser will shorten multiple spaces to one. e.g: "hello . . . forum!" (remove dots) would be shortened to "hello forum!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over what the string will be, you should consider including the semicolon for the reason Kolink described.

Either way, this will do the trick (and in this example, I include semicolons):

```
var string = "&nbsp;<a&nbsp;href='#'></a>";
string.replace("<a&nbsp;","<a ");
```

This looks for the phrase `<a&nbsp;` in the string and replaces it with `<a`.

Comment: Of course, well that was obvious.. Thanks Purmou for the brilliant and quick answer!

Comment: @user1199434: Actually, it wouldn't have worked. See my latest edit. (And if I've helped, it is of course helpful to accept answers).

Comment: This did actually work pretty well i just used string.replace("<a&nbsp;href","<a href"); ...

Answer (score 0):

The entity is `&nbsp;`, with a semicolon on the end. Just because the browser doesn't bother looking for the semicolon, doesn't mean it's optional. It is REQUIRED, otherwise the entity is mal-formed and a more strict browser might reject it.

That aside, your problem is incredibly simple to solve: Replace `/<a&nbsp/g` with `"<a "`.